# Force close when launching stock home screen from activity

Tags: java, android, android-intent, launcher, homescreen

I am trying to launch the stock home screen from an activity, but it keeps force closing. So far, I have an activity that displays a list of installed "homes". The user can choose one and it will launch the chosen home screen. This works fine for installed homes, but when I chose the stock (pre-installed) home, it will force close.

Here is what I am using to start the activity. I provided the `packagename` of the stock home for my device.

```
Intent startMain = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.android.launcher");
startMain.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
startMain.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(startMain);
```

Any help would be awesome as I don't understand why this works for most homes but not others.

**Log Cat:**

```
02-01 20:26:46.144: E/AndroidRuntime(7432): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-01 20:26:46.144: E/AndroidRuntime(7432): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.calsto.lockscreen/com.calsto.HomeWizard.NanohaLauncher}: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-01 20:26:46.144: E/AndroidRuntime(7432):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1956)
02-01 20:26:46.144: E/AndroidRuntime(7432):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
02-01 20:26:46.144: E/AndroidRuntime(7432):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
02-01 20:26:46.144: E/AndroidRuntime(7432):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
02-01 20:26:46.144: E/AndroidRuntime(7432):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-01 20:26:46.144: E/AndroidRuntime(7432):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-01 20:26:46.144: E/AndroidRuntime(7432):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
02-01 20:26:46.144: E/AndroidRuntime(7432):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-01 20:26:46.144: E/AndroidRuntime(7432):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-01 20:26:46.144: E/AndroidRuntime(7432):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:787)
02-01 20:26:46.144: E/AndroidRuntime(7432):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:554)
02-01 20:26:46.144: E/AndroidRuntime(7432):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-01 20:26:46.144: E/AndroidRuntime(7432): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-01 20:26:46.144: E/AndroidRuntime(7432):     at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1378)
02-01 20:26:46.144: E/AndroidRuntime(7432):     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3190)
02-01 20:26:46.144: E/AndroidRuntime(7432):     at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3297)
02-01 20:26:46.144: E/AndroidRuntime(7432):     at com.calsto.HomeWizard.NanohaLauncher.onCreate(NanohaLauncher.java:233)
02-01 20:26:46.144: E/AndroidRuntime(7432):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
02-01 20:26:46.144: E/AndroidRuntime(7432):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
02-01 20:26:46.144: E/AndroidRuntime(7432):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
02-01 20:26:46.144: E/AndroidRuntime(7432):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: If you want to go back to the home screen why not just call `finish();`?

Comment: The user choses a home screen to launch, not the default. So basically, i am attempting to launch any home screen even if its not set as the default home.